# Galaxy S4 emulator not loadind xlarge folder

Tags: android, android-layout

When i try to load my layout (layout-xlarge-land and layout-xlarge) for Galaxy s4 with 1920x1080 resolotion it goes to wrong one (layout-large-mdpi).
is there something wrong with my emulator setting ?

im using these setting for my avd  :

[image]

and for layout i have these folders :

```
layout-mdpi:
--a.xml
layout-land-mdpi:
--a.xml
layout-large-mdpi:
--a.xml
layout-land-large-mdpi:
--a.xml
layout-xlarge:
--a.xml
layout-xlarge-land:
--a.xml
layout-xxhdpi:
--a.xml
layout-land-xxhdpi:
--a.xml
```

and each xml layout file contain this view :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0.0dip"
    android:layout_height="0.0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" 
    android:id="@+id/mylayouttype"
    android:tag="layout-mdpi"/>
```

The tag part changes depend on folder name and layout type(land or normal)

in code i check for desire layout like this in start of application :

```
    setContentView(R.layout.a);
    View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.layouttype);
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Layout is : "+ v.getTag().toString());
```

it works for other device size but on S4 , it returns "layout-mdpi" instead of "layout-xlarge"

this is my manifest.xml :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="6"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try replace your folder's name to "layout-1920x1080"

Comment: thanks but it still goes into "layout-large-mdpi" folder

Comment: Please try delete "layout-large-mdpi" and run again?

Comment: after deleting "layout-large-mdpi" now emulator load "layout-xxhdpi" instead !

Comment: You could try replace your foler's name to "layout-nodpi-1920x1080" and run again .if it still do not work , I will has no idea for that ,sorry!

Comment: Ive deleted all other folder like xxhdpi , large-mdpi  and the first one works.
i find example here too :
http://code.google.com/p/kitsilano/source/browse/Kitsilano/res/layout-1920x1080/activity_main.xml?spec=svn1de19938d126554d74d2231154178ad493eae818&r=1de19938d126554d74d2231154178ad493eae818

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rename the xlarge folder to - "layout-1920x1080" this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You make your folder name **layout-xxhdpi** instead of previous one.